# New Google Identity Service Migration with PHP Client library

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-identity

I got a warning from google stating "**your client ID(s) use the legacy Google Sign-In web solution**".

And we are asked to **migrate to the new Google Identity Services**.

We do not use any JS library to sign-in. We have a **Google PHP Client library** for authentication and authorization.

Google still flagged our client Id and advised to migrate before March 31 2023.

Will this depreciation really affect us?
Can someone help me with the exact changes to be done on our end?

Answer (score 0):

The team has a system that can detect which projects are calling the endpoint used by the deprecated JavaScript sign-in library.   They send out emails to the owners of that project.  From what I understand from the team they don't know for a fact that you are using it they can just see that your project id is hitting it.

The Google APIs PHP client library does not hit this end point so that part of your code is not the source.

I would just double check around your team and make sure nothing else may be using the old JavaScript library. If you cant find anything then the easiest solution is to just wait once google starts rolling out the deprecation at the end of March someone will come find you if something breaks.

Comment: As per my understanding. It's just the Javascript Library that's affected. Other backend client libraries need not be changed. Is it right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.   Only the JavaScript sign-in in library is effected.